# How to manage Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008 R2?

Tags: hyper-v, remote-desktop, remote-access, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I've installed **Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008 R2** on a spare box. How do I configure and manage the server?

I configured as much as I could find to be

- *open*
- *on*
- *allow*
- etc.

Now back at my desk (Windows Vista 64-bit) I want to make the server do stuff, for example:

- create the RAID volume
- create virtual machines
- make it hyper

I can't remote desktop to it:

[image]

I can't use Computer Management to manage Hyper-V*ness*, or the drives:

[image]

I tried downloading the Windows Vista Management Tools for Hyper-V, but they apparently do not apply to my system:

[image]

There is no domain. I tried adding my desktop login/pass as an account on the server, but my 21-character password (including spaces and special characters) doesn't meet the server's password requirement.

---

That's what I've tried, but you can ignore all that. Let's start over:

**How do I manage Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008 R2?**

---

**Note:** Because of the Hyper-V limitations, I just repurposed the server and abandoned Hyper-V server. Hyper-V was an interesting idea, but not yet ready for real world production use.

As a result I won't be checking answers to see if they work (as if you should need a wiki to figure out how to configure a server). I'll make this a community wiki, so that others continue to have a place to figure out how to manage a Hyper-V server - but I'll no longer be monitoring it.

Comment: "Hyper-V was an interesting idea, but not yet ready for real world production use" - ohkay, we run VMWare which does the same stuff as Hyper-V and we have over 30 virtual servers running on a blade centre. Not ready for production use? Riiight

Comment: i'm sure it's technically quite capable.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to ask the obvious, but are the client & server both set to the same time & time zone?  I'm assuming you already set the remote properties to the "less secure" option in sysdm.cpl to get to this point?

As far as a user, I'd just create a user on the server and login using computername\username

Comment: Timezone: Yes.  Less secure: Yes, although Hyper-V server you configure it from a console mode UI.  Create user: i cannot, it doesn't accept the password.

Comment: Update: Looks like your suggestion did indeed let me connect with RDP. i fixed the timezone earlier today, and it didn't fix it right away. Now that i've come back to it few hours later it does work. Now i can connect to the empty desktop - but Hyper-V server doesn't let you manage the server locally.

Comment: Yes, the free download seems to come without a lot of the tools to make life easier, the walkthrough here may help http://www.netometer.com/video/tutorials/manage-microsoft-hyper-v-server-remotely-workgroup-vista/

Answer (score 0):

Check Out Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en

Quote:
Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 enables IT administrators to manage roles and features that are installed on remote computers that are running Windows Server 2008 R2 (and, for some roles and features, Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2003) from a remote computer that is running Windows 7. It includes support for remote management of computers that are running either the Server Core or full installation options of Windows Server 2008 R2, and for some roles and features, Windows Server 2008. Some roles and features on Windows Server 2003 can be managed remotely by using Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7, although the Server Core installation option is not available with the Windows Server 2003 operating system.

This feature is comparable in functionality to the Windows Server 2003 Administrative Tools Pack and Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 (SP1).

Comment: Similar to the other software package, "This update does not apply to your system."

Comment: Oops... Blew past the 'Windows Vista' part when reading. It may be that you need to have Windows 7 client to manage Hyper-V R2 but I'm not sure. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to success! Here are links to the key pieces I believe you need:

KB article [952627](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952627): Description of the Windows Vista Management Tools update for the release version of Hyper-V

KB article 952627 includes a link to the Remote Management Update for Windows Vista for x64-based Systems [download location](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=88208468-0ad6-47de-8580-085cba42c0c2&DisplayLang=en).

Finally, you can use the [CMDKEY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243(WS.10).aspx) utility on your Vista workstation to configure appropriate user credentials to authenticate to the Hyper-V host automagically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems as you.  [This](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HVRemote) wsf file and associated instructions got rid of all the problems I was having, now I can connect through the Hyper-V Manager snapin, as well as the Computer Management snapin, from a Vista SP2 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Domain/Worgroup architecture between the server machine and client you're attempting to use to connect remotely, there could be a lot of configuration to do.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HVRemote

The above tool will enable you to easily connect using Hyper-V Manager from a client workstation.

As for configuring the disks, I would suggest using the DISKPART command-line utility on the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue with your password not meeting the server's password requirement, you probably have the "Password must meet complexity requirements" policy enabled.

[This TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc264456.aspx) has the details. In a nutshell, with this option enabled, your password must meet the following criteria:

- Passwords cannot contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters.
- Passwords must be at least six characters in length.
- Passwords must contain characters from three of the following four categories:

  - English uppercase characters (A through Z).
  - English lowercase characters (a through z).
  - Base 10 digits (0 through 9).
  - Non-alphabetic characters (for example, !, $, #, %).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd start with John Howard's blog.  He's got a lot of tips and tools for configuring and managing Hyper-V on Server Core (which is what Microsoft Hyper-V Server is.)

Start here:

http://blogs.technet.com/jhoward/archive/2008/11/14/configure-hyper-v-remote-management-in-seconds.aspx